# Bundler attempted to update rails but its version stayed the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to update the rails 5.0.7 to 5.2 but it is showing that

```
Bundler attempted to update rails but its version stayed the same
```

the command which I tried to update are:-

```
rails app:update
```

but it is not updating the rails even I tried running the below code

```
bundle update rails
```

Comment: Did you change rails version in Gemfile?

Comment: Can you paste your `Gemfile.lock` here? It definitely should contain a dependency on rails, that doesn't allow you to upgrade it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For people who came here to update their regular gem in my case I was trying to update

```rb
gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
```

this gem to version 3.2.1

It was limited with 3.2 so basically change it to

```rb
gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.3'
```

please before updating version always look your gemfile.lock if there is blocking dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

This can mean one of two things:

1. You have a dependency for rails (a package that depends on rails in a version < 5.2
2. You have specified a version for the rails (or it's gems) in your Gemfile, like `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.6'` or `gem 'activerecord', '5.0'`

On a side note, when updating rails, do not upgrade from 5.0 to 5.2, follow the upgrading guides at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html
and do an incremental upgrade (one version at a time)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue trying to update a few stubborn gems. I recommend the standalone gem [bundler-stats](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/bundler-stats/1.1.0) for figuring out what bundler is thinking, especially `bundle-stats versions SOME_GEM_NAME`. For more info check out [this blog post](https://olivierlacan.com/posts/why-wont-bundle-update/).